# How to fix: ProgrammingErrorsAlreadyExists'django_content_type'

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

When I run the server it gives this message on console:

> "You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work
> properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth,
> contenttypes, sessions.

Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them."

When I try to run `python manage.py migrate`.
It shows this message at the bottom:

> "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]There is
> already an object named 'django_content_type' in the database."

Comment: I'd take a look at the `django_migrations` table for whats been applied. It looks like you'll need to run at least the initial content types migration with the `--fake` flag. Or just delete the db & try again?

Comment: @markwalker_ It gives the same. I have data in MSSQL, I want to make new website by using this data. But it is not working with MSSQL. Sometimes it give this error `KeyError: 'include'`
Will it possible to work with existing data in mssql?

Comment: You've got a database from another django project that you are trying to reuse?

Comment: No the second project isn't a Django project. 
Actually I'm working on a project, to make a monthly report of orders. The existing data came from ASP.NET website.

Comment: Ok, well I'd go by my original comment first - you need to figure out what django tables already exist because some appear to exist and they're causing problems.

Comment: When try to migrate by using `python manage.py migrate` it gives this error: `ProgrammingError: ('42S01', "[42S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'django_content_type' in the database. (2714) (SQLExecDirectW)")`

Comment: Hey @markwalker_ , I resolve this problem. 
There was a file automatically created in my project `"db.sqlite3"`. I simply delete this file and run again `python manage.py migrate` and its done.

Comment: Now again same issue came. Don't know what's happening

Comment: Based on the presence of a sqlite database, that sounds like your settings aren't quite right. A sqlite database is the default database, so your connection settings for MSSQL aren't always being used.

Comment: Yes @markwalker_, I got the solution. 
When we make any migrations, it will create an object name `django_content_type` in the database. We have to delete that object or table first to move to an other database.